# MongoDB Spring - the id is stored in a different format

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data

In my code, I declare an Entity having

```
id: UUID
```

When I perform a save operation through POSTMAN, I am getting a response where entity id is shown as UUID:

```
id: "45bb2fa6-62c1-47fa-ab89-482a55d58dbb"
```

But in the database it is being stored as LUUID, or maybe like `BinData(3, "sdmsnj0--snjs")`

Where does this difference comes from? Why the api returns me a normal UUID, but in the database I can see only UUID or BinData ?

How is it possible to convert UUID to LUUID or BinData?

Answer (score 1):

The following from the Robo3T page:

*MongoDB itself stores UUIDs as Binary fields and when such Binary fields are accessed from software, MongoDB drivers usually convert their value as found in the database to language-specific UUID or GUID objects.
For example, when you read a UUID from a MongoDB database using the Java driver, an object of type java.util.UUID will be returned. The C# driver on the other hand will return a struct of type System.GUID.
This makes it very convenient and easy to work with the UUID data type from your application code.*

LUUID is a legacy UUID. If you want to use UUID [do this](https://blog.jcore.com/2020/03/saving-uuids-instead-of-luuids-in-mongodb-with-java/). Or maybe [update drivers](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/how-to-store-a-uuid-with-binary-subtype-0x04-using-the-mongodb-java-driver/13184).